# What's the difference in rows and sections in NSIndexPath in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsindexpath

I can't seem to see what exactly a section is. I know what a row is in UITableViewController, but what is a section. Is it a separate piece of information? I'm a beginner and couldn't find a clear answer anywhere else on the web.

Comment: Rows can be grouped into sections. You table must have at least 1 section, but you could have sections for each letter in a list of contacts or each date in an event listing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A section is a group of rows. For example, in the settings app, different rows are grouped into sections.

Sections can have titles and allow for information to be broken apart.